# C#: supplying multiple elements, when the element is a column and not a table in my dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, schema

I have the following XSD Schema:

```
<xs:element name="seg" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Informações de Seguro da Carga</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="infResp">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Informações do responsável pelo seguro da carga</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="respSeg">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Responsável pelo seguro</xs:documentation>
                                <xs:documentation>Preencher com:
                                    1- Emitente do MDF-e;
                                    22 - Responsável pela contratação do serviço de transporte (contratante)    
                                    Dados obrigatórios apenas no modal Rodoviário, depois da lei 11.442/07. Para os demais modais esta informação é opcional.</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:element name="CNPJ" type="TCnpj">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Número do CNPJ do responsável pelo seguro</xs:documentation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Obrigatório apenas se responsável pelo seguro for (2) responsável pela contratação do transporte - pessoa jurídica</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="CPF" type="TCpf">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Número do CPF do responsável pelo seguro</xs:documentation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Obrigatório apenas se responsável pelo seguro for (2) responsável pela contratação do transporte - pessoa física</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="infSeg" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Informações da seguradora</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="xSeg">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Nome da Seguradora</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="TString">
                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="CNPJ" type="TCnpjOpc">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Número do CNPJ da seguradora</xs:documentation>
                                <xs:documentation>Obrigatório apenas se responsável pelo seguro for (2) responsável pela contratação do transporte - pessoa jurídica</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="nApol" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Número da Apólice</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation>Obrigatório pela lei 11.442/07 (RCTRC)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="TString">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="nAver" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Número da Averbação</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation>Informar as averbações do seguro</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="TString">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Today my code is the following:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

    Dim drSeg As DataRow = dset.Tables("seg").NewRow
    With drSeg
        .Item("seg_Id") = x
        .Item("infMdfe_Id") = drinfMdfe.Item("infMdfe_Id")

        .Item("nApol") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("nApol"))
        .Item("nAver") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("nAver"))
    End With
    dset.Tables("seg").Rows.Add(drSeg)

    Dim drInfResp As DataRow = dset.Tables("infResp").NewRow
    With drInfResp

        .Item("respSeg") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("respSeg"))
        If NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("CNPJ_respSeg")) <> "" Then
            .Item("CNPJ") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("CNPJ_respSeg"))
            .Item("CPF") = "null"
        Else
            .Item("CNPJ") = "null"
            .Item("CPF") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("CPF_respSeg"))
        End If

        .Item("seg_Id") = drSeg.Item("seg_Id")

    End With
    dset.Tables("infResp").Rows.Add(drInfResp)

    Dim drInfSeg As DataRow = dset.Tables("infSeg").NewRow
    With drInfSeg

        .Item("xSeg") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("xSeg"))
        .Item("CNPJ") = NullBranco(wDataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(x)("CNPJ_seg"))

        .Item("seg_Id") = drSeg.Item("seg_Id")

    End With
    dset.Tables("infSeg").Rows.Add(drInfSeg)

Next
```

In the last element, i had the "nAver", it is a simpleType but the maxOccurs is "unbounded". In the current version I can add only one information for this element, but I need multiple. How can I do this using DataSets?

Considering that my output in XML should be:

```
<seg>
    <infResp>
        <respSeg>1</respSeg>
        <CNPJ>94857307000157</CNPJ>
    </infResp>
    <infSeg>
        <xSeg>TOKIO MARINE SEGURADORA S/A</xSeg>
        <CNPJ />
    </infSeg>
    <nApol>696049</nApol>
    <nAver>1111111</nAver>
    <nAver>2222222</nAver>
    <nAver>3333333</nAver>
    <nAver>4444444</nAver>
    <nAver>5555555</nAver>
</seg>
```

Comment: Your XSD properly expresses your intent that there can be multiple `nAver` elements, and, in fact, your XML is valid against your XSD.  What makes you say that you *can add one information for this element, but I need multiple*?

Comment: Using my code I only can add one <nAver> tag. The XML presented is what I want to achieve (multiple tags).

Comment: You show no code that attempts to add multiple `nAver` elements, and you show no error indicating that you're blocked in doing so.  What have you tried that's failed to work?

Comment: That's my fail. I don't know how to deal with the "nAver" element, because it is not a table (complex type) in my DataSet, but only a column. What i'm looking for, is someone that could help me inserting many lines for a column (simple type).

Comment: So, you really have a design question about how to map trees to tables (note fundamental mismatch), but you've buried it as code question hidden beneath an XML/XSD question?